# Parsing log file, ambiguous delimiter

Tags: c#, parsing

I have to parse a log file and not sure how to best take different pieces of each line. The problem I am facing is original developer used ':' to delimit tokens which was a bit idiotic since the line contains timestamp which itself contains ':'!

A sample line looks something like this:

```
transaction_date_time:[systemid]:sending_system:receiving_system:data_length:data:[ws_name]

2019-05-08 15:03:13:494|2019-05-08 15:03:13:398:[192.168.1.2]:ABC:DEF:67:cd71f7d9a546ec2b32b,AACN90012001000012,OPNG:[WebService.SomeName.WebServiceModule::WebServiceName]
```

I have no problem reading the log file and accessing each line but no sure how to get the pieces parsed?

Comment: The timestamp is of fixed length. If the format is consistent, then you can take first N symbols (parse datetime using format), skip 1 (check that it is a `|`), take next N symbols (parse datetime using format), skip 1 symbol (check that it is `:`), take symbols until `:` (parse as IP address), and so on.

Comment: `^(.*?)\:\[(.*?)\]:(.*?)\:(.*?)\:\d+\:(.*?)\:(\[.*?\])$`? Split the first group by `|` if needed.

Comment: Not to well versed in RE, how do you split 1st group by '|'?

Comment: Assume that `input` is your input string and `pattern` is the Regex: `var result = Regex.Match(input, pattern);`. The the first Group contains `2019-05-08 15:03:13:494|2019-05-08 15:03:13:398`. So you can split it with `var dates = result.Groups[1].Value.Split('|');`. You get a string array with the two dates (as strings, of course). The regex assumes that, for example, `[192.168.1.2]` is actually inside brackets. Modify as needed

Comment: Note that `Group[0]` contains the capture, which is the full string here. So, your results are included in `Group[1]` to `Group[6]`.

Comment: Thanks. RE looks good and match passes and returns true but when I use Groups[x] somehow the number "67" is skipped. I get the timestamps, systemid, sending and receiving systems and then the data; no "data length" and the last index (Groups[7]) ends up being empty. I used: sTimestamp = match.Groups[1].Value;sSystemID = match.Groups[2].Value;sSendingSys = match.Groups[3].Value;sReceivingSys = match.Groups[4].Value;sDataLnegth = match.Groups[5].Value; <-- this shows content of "data"

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wrote it here. The data length is not in a capturing group. Use this: `"^(.*?)\:\[(.*?)\]:(.*?)\:(.*?)\:(\d+)\:(.*?)\:(\[.*?\])$"`

Comment: Perfect! Please change your comment(s) to answer and i will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the input string is not exactly *splittable*, because of the delimiter char is also part of the content, a simple regex expression can be used instead.
Simple but probably fast enough, even with the default settings.

The different parts of the input string can be separated with these capturing groups:

```
string pattern = @"^(.*?)\|(.*?):\[(.*?)\]:(.*?):(.*?):(\d+):(.*?):\[(.*)\]$";
```

This will give you 8 groups + 1 (`Group[0]`) which contains the whole string.

Using the [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex) class, simply pass a string to parse (named `line`, here) and the regex (named `pattern`) to the [Match()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match) method, using default settings:

```
var result = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
```

The [Groups.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value) property returns the result of each capturing group. For example, the two dates:

```
var dateEnd = DateTime.ParseExact(result.Groups[1].Value, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:ttt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
var dateStart = DateTime.ParseExact(result.Groups[2].Value, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:ttt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
```

The `IpAddress` is extracted with: `\[(.*?)\]`.
You could give a name to this grouping, so it's more clear what the value refers to. Simply add a string, prefixed with `?` and enclosed in `<>` or single quotes `'` to name the grouping:

```
...\[(?<IpAddress>.*?)\]...
```

Note, however, that naming a group will modify the `Regex.Groups` indexing: the un-named groups will be inserted first, the named groups after. So, naming only the  `IpAddress` group will cause it to become the last item, `Groups[8]`. Of course you can name all the groups and the indexing will be preserved.

```
var hostAddress = IPAddress.Parse(result.Groups["IpAddress"].Value);
```

This patter should allow a *medium* machine to parse `130,000~150,000` strings per second.
You'll have to test it to find the *perfect* pattern. For example, the first match (corresposnding to the first date): `(.*?)\|`, is much faster if non-greedy (using the *? lazy quantifier). The opposite for the last match: `\[(.*)\]`. The pattern used by [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56260599/7444103) is even faster than the one used here.

See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) for a detailed description on the use and meaning of each token.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex I was able to parse everything.  It looks like the data came from excel because the faction of seconds has a colon instead of a period.  c# does not like the colon so I had to replace colon with a period.  I also parsed from right to left to get around the colon issues.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program1
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line = "";
            int rowCount = 0;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string pattern = @"^(?'time'.*):\[(?'systemid'[^\]]+)\]:(?'sending'[^:]+):(?'receiving'[^:]+):(?'length'[^:]+):(?'data'[^:]+):\[(?'ws_name'[^\]]+)\]";

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (++rowCount != 1) //skip header row
                    {
                        Log_Data newRow = new Log_Data();
                        Log_Data.logData.Add(newRow);
                        Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);

                        newRow.ws_name = match.Groups["ws_name"].Value;
                        newRow.data = match.Groups["data"].Value;
                        newRow.length = int.Parse(match.Groups["length"].Value);
                        newRow.receiving_system = match.Groups["receiving"].Value;
                        newRow.sending_system = match.Groups["sending"].Value;
                        newRow.systemid  = match.Groups["systemid"].Value;
                        //end data is first then start date is second
                        string[] date = match.Groups["time"].Value.Split(new char[] {'|'}).ToArray();
                        string replacePattern = @"(?'leader'.+):(?'trailer'\d+)";
                        string stringDate = Regex.Replace(date[1], replacePattern, "${leader}.${trailer}", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
                        newRow.startDate = DateTime.Parse(stringDate);
                        stringDate = Regex.Replace(date[0], replacePattern, "${leader}.${trailer}", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
                        newRow.endDate = DateTime.Parse(stringDate );
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
    public class Log_Data
    {
        public static List<Log_Data> logData = new List<Log_Data>();

        public DateTime startDate { get; set; } //transaction_date_time:[systemid]:sending_system:receiving_system:data_length:data:[ws_name]
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
        public string systemid { get; set; }
        public string sending_system { get; set; }
        public string receiving_system { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
        public string ws_name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Data comes from a text file (log file); also I have no control over its content so cannot change colon to period.

Comment: I did in code so you do not have to change the input.  I needed to replace the colon with a period to parse the Date string to a DateTime object.

Comment: I see; thanks. I will give this a try. Thank you again for quick response.